# Impulse applied to sprite at angle and speed

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, physics

I'm using andengine and box2d to generate a game like paper toss.
What I can't calculate is the correct vector for the first parameter in the following function to make the ball go up in the correct speed and height (the idea is that the ball height does not exceed the screen height):

```
pelota_body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(pointX, impulse), pelota_body.getWorldCenter());
```

In pointX I use the value `vectorXPoint-(CAMERA_WIDTH/2)`and it goes in the direction of the vector drawn by the finger, but the impulse value I can't seem to get it right and whatever value I use (aprox 400) works different on every device.

Answer (score 1):

In order the body to travel height `h` before falling down you need it's initial vertical velocity:

`v_y = sqrt(2*g*h)`, where `g` is the gravity acceleration.

You can calculate the impulse based on this `v_y` or just use `SetLinearVelocity` method.

**EDIT**

```
//box2d source
inline void b2Body::ApplyLinearImpulse(const b2Vec2& impulse, const b2Vec2& point)
{
    if (m_type != b2_dynamicBody)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (IsAwake() == false)
    {
        SetAwake(true);
    }
    m_linearVelocity += m_invMass * impulse;
    m_angularVelocity += m_invI * b2Cross(point - m_sweep.c, impulse);
}
```

So I would just set the velocity

Comment: and how do you calculate the impulse with that inicial velocity v_y ?

Comment: @vrunoa: just take a look at box2d source